# React Native: Images URI are not working on release apk

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-paper

I'm using `react-native-paper` to develop my application's UI.

I want to show an image in the `Card` component of react-native-paper, using `Card.Cover`.

The image is shown normally when I use the debug apk, but it doesn't load when I use the release apk.

Below is my component and the image I'm trying to load:

```
const image = {
    name: 'Some Test Image', 
    uri: 'http://www.memoriarondonense.com.br/public/timthumb.php?w=780&src=http://www.memoriarondonense.com.br/public/upload/calendario-historico/7e6c713365c50ec0fd6bfada96a1f034.jpg&m=img/65.png'
};

<Card style={{margin: '2%'}}>
    <Card.Cover
        source={image.uri.includes('.pdf') ? require('../../../../assets/pdf-logo.png') : {uri: image.uri}}
    />
</Card>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem is that the release apk doesn't load images with HTTP, I changed the protocol to HTTPS and it worked correctly.